# In Azure Devops, how do I create a query that shows the iteration start date and end date?

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

I can't find the selection for Iteration start date and End date in the columns selector.  Is there a way of adding that data to the result.

I am thinking it may be doable in WIQL.

UPDATE: Using the following fields in the WIQL generates no values

```
    [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate],
    [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Azure Devops, how do I create a query that shows the iteration start date and end date?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Azure devops work item query not support to filter Iteration using Start/End Dates.

To get start data and finish date for each iteration, you should use the [REST API to list iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/Iterations/List?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-4.1) instead of using queries:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.0
```

Then you can get each iteration's start date and finish date from response:

[image]

**Update:**

> I'm not looking to filter by start and end dates, I just want it to
>   show the start and end dates in the report.

If you want to show the iteration start and end dates in the report, I am afraid currently there is no way to do that, even with WIQL.

Just like what I said above, **Azure devops work item query not support to filter Iteration using Start/End Dates.**. There is no any Column options about the iteration start and end dates, just iteration path, so we could not show the iteration start and end dates in the query/report, WIQL is just a command line / script mode for UI query.

On the other hand, as we know, the Query is list the work items based on field criteria you specify using queries, so, all the result are about the workitem info, but if you open any workitem, we could not get the **iteration start and end dates, just iteration path**, so, that the reason why we could not get the iteration start and end dates. To get the iteration start and end dates, we have to go the `Sprints` or use the REST API.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not looking to filter by start and end dates, I just want it to show the start and end dates in the report.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, Check if my updated answer give any help.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to locate this thread on:
[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22f36827-d197-4d3c-9d3b-7866006225c6/query-for-work-items-with-date-but-no-time?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)

It looks like you can query for something like:
[image]

Comment: The asker asks about start date and end date in WIQL, not by creating/setting up sprint display on portal.

Comment: Came out blank I'll put that in the OP since I can't post images